# An unwelcomed url is working in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes, dns, subdomain, zero

What my problem is that an unwelcomed url is working like www.domain.com/0 and showing me the main page.

Moreover, pages subdomain.domain.com/0 are working like subpages as well.

I am using codeigniter. I checked the routes.php and there is nothing related to zero. Is it related with CI? What's wrong with 0 suffix?

Comment: check your `.htaccess` file, without some code of your primary controller its hard to tell..

Comment: I won't put this as an answer because I'm not 100% sure about the 2nd part. But 1st from CI we know this. `www.domain.com` is really `www.domain.com/default_controller` which is really `www.domain.com/default_controller/index` adding a 0 to the end means calling `index(0)` in `default_controller` which if I'm not mistaken is valid in PHP even if the function is defined as simply `public function index()`. Someone with better knowledge can hopefully confirm this or teach me something.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `0` is an empty value. Codeigniter checks if the uri is empty or not. If empty it loads default controller.

The real question is, how does it matter for you?

```
$uri = '0';
if (empty($uri))
    echo 'Oh my! Lets load default controller!';
```

Comment: it does not seems good. Is it possible to remove it or change zero settings in core?

Comment: How does it matter to anyone that `/0` is accessable? You don't refer to that url and no visitors will notice it. I guess you could do a `$route['0'] = 'errorz'` if it's a must.

Comment: actually pages ending with zero are being indexed by server. So there happens dupplicates. I think that is a problem.

Comment: `if ($this->uri->segment(1) === '0') redirect(trim(current_url(), '0/'), 'location', '301');` would help you if you're concerned by spiders.

Comment: ok it seems it will help. But where am I supposed to run this code? I mean in which class? Because I am going to use it in every subdomain and base domain.

Comment: Using [Hooks](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html) or through autoloaded helper, model or library.

Comment: Ok I enabled hooks and I am using pre_controller as a hook and it doesn't work. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Use `post_controller_constructor` instead. `$CI =& get_instance()` isn't defined in `pre_controller`. And replace `$this` with `$CI`.

Comment: Ok I found the problem. File_path configuration in hooks was wrong. I check using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] whether there is a 0 at the end, then I redirect using 301. Thanks for help Robin.